# Big Integer Class C++

Tags: c++

I'd like to write an unsigned Big Int library in C++ as an exercise, however I would like to stay away from using the traditional vector of chars storing individual digits. Due to the amount of memory wasted by this approach.

Would using a vector of unsigned short ints (ie. 16 bit postive integers) work, or is there a better way of doing this?

To Clarify, I would store "12345678" as {1234, 5678}.

Comment: It should work, and as unsigned overflow is specified as a 2**n modulo, you would have a standard defined behaviour. The only drawback is that you will have to specifically implement substraction...

Comment: I'd use a vector of `unsigned long` if it's memory you want to save. Since `short int` might be still 64 bits of memory depending on architecture

Comment: actually, the first approach is better because each character will take 8-bits (1 byte) to store instead of 16-bit in your approach.

Comment: @BemwaMalak I intend on storing more than one character in each Integer slot.

Comment: Oh, I see sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: @al3c: it should not be a problem, provided you do not rely on a specific size, but use what `limits.h` contains...

Comment: @SergeBallesta What do you mean by this? I intend to store "12345678" as {1234, 5678} for example.

Comment: I would advise you to instead use as much values as each element can contain. So I would store (assuming 16 bits shorts) `0x123456` as `{0x3456, 0x12}`  to get a very efficient storage. But I must admit that division is then far from a piece of cake to implement...

Comment: *I would store "12345678" as {1234, 5678}.* -- Have you worked this out with pencil and paper first in terms of how you will add these numbers, where they will be stored, etc?  If so, then there shouldn't be an issue.  Without all the plans written down on paper, it is very easy to paint yourself into a corner writing code that will not work, thus having to start over again.

Comment: @SergeBallesta How would you do it to simplify division?

Comment: storage is the least of your problems. how will you implement binary operations

Comment: @BenBorg: Not really thought about it... I just remember that when I played with that (loooong time ago) the division was the hardest part. But if I correctly remember, the key for division and multiplication is to use a type twice as large for the individual operations (so a 32 bit integer if your vector strores 16 bits ones). Once this is done, the good old algorithms we learned when we were children were enough...

Comment: If you want to store decimal digits, you can store each digit in 4 bits, i.e. 2 per byte.

Comment: @ldgorman I assumed I would need to think about that once I've decided on the underlying data structure

Comment: @nielsen this is what first came to mind however C++'s smallest integer data type is a 16 bit int.

Comment: @BenBorg no, `char` is an integral type too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing digits in corresponding `char`s is certainly **not** traditional, because of the reason you stated - it wastes memory. Using N-bit integers to store N corresponding bits is the usual approach. It wastes no memory, and is actually easier to implement (though harder to debug, because the integers are typically large).

Yes, using `unsigned short int` for individual units of information (generalized "digits") is a good idea. However, consider using 32-bit or 64-bit integers - they are closer to the size of the CPU registers, so your implementation will be more efficient.

General idea of syntax:

```
class BigInt
{
private:
    std::vector<uint64_t> digits;
};
```

You should decide whether you store least significant digits in smaller or larger indices. I think smaller is better (because addition, subtraction and multiplication algorithms start from LSB), but it's your choice.

Comment: Could you clarify what  "Using N-bit integers to store N corresponding bits" means.

Comment: @BenBorg Instead of storing decimal digits, you store your numbers in base 2^n.  For example, for 16-bit `unsigned short`, `12345678` (`0xBC614E`) could be stored as `{188, 24910}` (`{0xBC, 0x614E}`} in base-2^16 (`188 * 2**16 + 24910 == 12345678`).  That can be extended to any size of digit

Comment: @MilesBudnek thanks this rly helps!!